# Scrolling with CSS gradient background

Tags: html, css

[Here's the page.](http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist426015/comisto/ementa) The space below "Pedidos", that scrolls, has a gradient background. My problem here is that I want the background to continue scrolling and repeating as I scroll, but it just stays fixed. I've experimented on a simple page, and it does scroll, so why doesn't it happen here? Here's the relevant styling for the section:

```
.pedidos #list {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 405px - 10px);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #e1e1e1, #e1e1e1 35px, #cdcdcd 35px, #cdcdcd 70px);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the current code of the area (the list item is just there to create space to demonstrate):

```
<ul id="list">
  <li style="height: 1000px; background-color: transparent;">a</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML structure, and more clear explanation on what you want to get.

Comment: The background is still when you scroll. I want that not to happen i.e. I want it to scroll too.

Comment: So, as you scroll, you want the lines to stay in place (the background), but the list items to scroll on top of them?

Comment: No, I want the lines to move, but they stay in the same place.

Answer (score 4):

This should solve the issue. `Background-attachment:fixed` fixes the background attachment to the viewport.

Edit: in order to make the background scroll along with the rest of the page, use `background-attachment:scroll`

```
.pedidos #list {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 405px - 10px);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #e1e1e1, #e1e1e1 35px, #cdcdcd 35px, #cdcdcd 70px);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment:scroll;
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. The background is already fixed, which I don't want to happen. I want the background to move.

Comment: I edited my answer to make the background move: use `scroll` instead of `fixed`

Comment: In that case, the issue may be caused by elements or styling elsewhere on the page, (maybe a wrapper?) because that ought to work.

Comment: It appears as if the `overflow` property, set to `scroll` or `overlay` is causing this... Yeah, it makes sense, because I'm also setting the `max-height`. How can I cut off the section without having to set a specific `height`?

Comment: hm, that shouldn't be the cause I think, although I've never seen `overlay` used as a value for `overflow`, and MDN doesn't list it as a possible value either, nor does the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow). Hence, your `overflow` value may be an issue

Comment: No, the `overlay` is not an issue. It is fairly new, it basically makes the scrollbar overlap the element, taking no space from it. I've decided to give up on the idea I had and go for a simpler approach, but thanks fro the heml anyway.